# Samsung Galaxy S5 Stuck in boot loop & will not enter recovery mode

Tags: samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 Model SM-G900V stuck in a boot loop.  Unknown Android version, but the phone is stock with no mods. I've tried the following:

Replaced the battery with a known working battery
Soft Reset
Tried every key combination possible
Entered Download mode and re-flashed with a stock ROM
Phone will not enter recovery mode shows blue text on top right and then also reboots into a boot loop before entering recovery mode.  After it reboots it still shows the blue text on the top right but never gets past that.
I am able to enter maintenance boot and tried safe mode and clicked on factory reset which then brings me to the screen for recovery booting and then enters a boot loop again.

The fireware I have tried is:
G900VVRU2DQL1_G900VVZW2DQL1_G900VVRU2DQL1_HOME.tar.md5
&
G900VVRU2DPG2_G900VVZW2DPG2_G900VVRU2DPG2_HOME.tar.md5

I also tried to use ODIN and replace the PIT with the following:  KLTE_USA_VZW.pit

All Flashing was sucessfull

- power + volume up (in several combinations of holding / pressing
- power + volume down
- power + volume up + volume down
- power + home
- power + home + volume up
- power + home + volume down
- home + volume up
- home + volume down

Comment: Have you tried connecting it via a PC!? Such as a Linux with ADB and fastboot installed!? Sometimes you might require using a PC to reload the bootloader and rom via a sideload.

Comment: Yes, I've tried re-loading the ROM from a PC several times with 5 different ROMS.  No good.

Comment: I've taken it to Verizon and the tech their told me that since it won't enter recovery mode chances are that is it a hardware failure.